# Master Detail Flow .. selection on rotate broken after override of getView

Tags: android, selection, master-detail, getview

I'm trying to user the standard Master Detail Flow from Android Studio but I want to replace the List items on the left with a custom View.

I'm able to do this just fine by creating my own adapter and then overriding the getView() method and returning the custom Layout that I want to represent each item.

As soon as I do this though, the listSelector doesn't remember the selected item when I rotate the device. I'm obviously not implementing something correctly when I override the getView() method for the Adapter but I can't seem to figure out what.

Comment: I've push the source to GitHub here: https://github.com/WarrickF/DFragTest1/

Comment: This is where I'm overriding getView() - https://github.com/WarrickF/DFragTest1/blob/master/app/src/main/java/app/com/victorioussolutions/dfragtest1/ContentAdapter.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save current position and restore it from onCreateView.

```
   private int currentCheckedPosition = 0;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(menuListener);
    listView.setItemChecked(currentCheckedPosition, true);
    ...
}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener menuListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            listView.setItemChecked(currentCheckedPosition = position, true);
            ...
    }
};
```

**UPD**
This should work. Replace code in ItemListFragment

```
public class ItemListFragment extends Fragment
{
//    private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION; //if you want to nothing selected on activity start
    private int mActivatedPosition = 0;//if you want to first item selected on activity start
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        setRetainInstance(true);
        super.onAttach(activity);
        if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ContentAdapter mAdapter = new ContentAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, android.R.id.text1, DummyContent.ITEMS);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_activity_list, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        listView.setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, true);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
        return view;
    }
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            listView.setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition = position, true);
            if (getActivity() instanceof Callbacks) {
                ((Callbacks) getActivity()).onItemSelected(DummyContent.ITEMS.get(position).id);
            }
        }
    };

    public interface Callbacks
    {
        void onItemSelected(String id);
    }
}
```

**layout/fancy_activity_list_item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some Content Here"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ContentAdapter**

```
public class ContentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>
{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<DummyContent.DummyItem> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fancy_activity_list_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }
        DummyContent.DummyItem dummyItem = getItem(position);
        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(dummyItem.content);
        return view;
    }
}
```

And you need to set **minSdkVersion 14** in build.gradle
It needed to set **android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"** to list Item layout.

Comment: Sure. I added a note to the original question with a link to the Git repo

Comment: Thanks, I've been trying to get this working but OnItemClickListener just won't fire. I've found all kinds of crazy reasons on my Google searches but non of the suggestions seems to work. they all seem to suggest the item is click is being stole by a child in the list but I have not been able to figure out why yet. I pushed the latest changes ...

Comment: @Warrick FitzGerald try to replace public class ItemListFragment extends ListFragment to public class ItemListFragment extends Fragment

Comment: That did seem to work, although I have no idea why? Also as soon as I change getView in the ContentAdapter to return my custom item view (fancy_activity_list_item) the select doesn't work at all.

Comment: @Warrick FitzGerald are you shure you change ListFragment to Fragment? I forked your repository, change "extends ListFragment" to "extends Fragment" and its work. You need to change it and import android.support.v4.app.Fragment. In your last commit I see comment "OnItemClickListener not working" but ItemListFragment extends ListFragment, not the Fragment.

Comment: @Warrick FitzGerald did you try? I write this code to help you, if you realy need this.

Comment: sorry, been very busy. I'm not sure why it wasn't checked in that with the extends changed to Fragement, but I just tested again and it def. does not work for me. I just pushed in the code again and cheked that the changes show up on GitHub.

Comment: I've been testing on a tablet (so I have a two pane view) .. and then I select an item it does not stay selected.

Comment: @Warrick FitzGerald tested it in a teblet. Everything works fine. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/976178/device-2015-09-02-030513.png Try to rebuild project and run again. Build->Rebuild. Does now OnClickListener works and than item not selected after rotation? Or OnClickListener sill doesnt work?

Comment: Yes, I even cloned the project to another folder and compiled from there just be be sure there wasn't anything odd going on. From your screenshot it does not look like your running my code though. Once I realized this I realized that you are not returning a custom layout from the getView call in  the ContentAdapter class. If I revert to return super.getView(position, convertView, parent); then it works as you describe, but the code that I posted is returning a custom layout which seems like it's what's causing the problems.

Comment: in getView  ... return LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fancy_activity_list_item, parent, false); ... is what's causing my select problems.

Comment: OMG it works .. Hooorray!!!!! Thank you, thank you!! The only problem is that I'm getting a warning saying that android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator" only works with API 11 and my min = 10.

Comment: How on earth did you debug that?

Comment: @Warrick FitzGerald see the end of the answer  - you need to set minSdkVersion 14 in build.gradle. You do not need to set minSdkVersion less than 14, because its very small devices. Over 94%(as far as I remember) in the world works in minSdkVersion 14. Set 14 and forget about it.

Comment: @Warrick FitzGerald well... I just have some experience, thats it ;-)

Comment: @Warrick FitzGerald you are welcome :-) Its maybe hard just for the first look, but you shouldnt give up and everething comes with the time. 99% answers already in stackoverflow. You just need to google it and try. Good luck :-)